# Error using map in fatfree php

Tags: fat-free-framework

When putting Employee.php class in the same directory with index.php every thing is working fine

index.php:

```
<?php
$f3=require('lib/base.php');
$f3->config('config.ini');
$f3->map('/employee','Employee');
$f3->run();
```

When putting Employee.php class under a directory, app for examle and running the following index.php

```
<?php
$f3=require('lib/base.php');
$f3->config('config.ini');
$f3->map('/employee','app\Employee');
$f3->run();
```

I am getting an error

> Internal Server Error
>
> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Employee
>
> • /home/zaky/Development/kinder/app/Employee.php:2

Employee.php:

```
<?php   
class Employee{
    function get() {die("get---");}
    function post() {die("post---");}
    function put() {die("put---");}
    function delete() {die("delete---");}
}
```

Comment: Do you include the employee.php by hand somewhere else? Also: please post your `config.ini`.

Comment: No.  [globals]

DEBUG=3

Comment: I also commented the set config with no changes

Comment: Please try to define your AUTOLOAD var in your config.ini like the following: AUTOLOAD=app/

Comment: @sascha Post the comment as an answer, will be easy for others to find.